# I accidentally shared my C drive – what should I be worried about?

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems

I accidentally shared my C drive on a Windows 7 machine, which was set to allow everyone with full control (read/write...) for a few months! The machine is behind a router with firewall in a home network.

I would like to know what my exposure was and who could've accessed my files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everybody who managed to get into your network was able to access your files. Assuming that your router firewall was enabled and your WLAN (if you have one) is encrypted, that means that only you and everyone else who normally is in your network had access.

Comment: Is network access logged any where on windows by default?

Comment: This is really a good question, maybe you should open a second question for this.

Comment: I know the answer too, so just post the question :)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/334697/is-network-access-logged-any-where-on-windows-by-default

Answer (score 0):

"The machine is behind a router with firewall in a home network" - assuming you used simple file sharing, whoever did it had the same privileges as a guest account - so they probably would be able to see nearly everything, and edit whatever they had the priviledges to edit. Outside the network, no access.

So.. "who" - anyone with network access. "What?" - everything. Unless you're worried about specific things, it probably amounts to nothing.

Answer (score -2):

In fact if you have a custom firewall running on your machine (I'm not sure about windows 7 integrated firewall) it will record by default any access to your machine (app XX connected to IP YY at time & date). Knowing that and filtering the results will allow you to see who accessed your files. I'm sure Comodo Personal Firewall (Freeware) allows it, not sure if all firewalls do. Anyway Comodo might not be the best choice for beginners ... I suggest you install a firewall in case in the future you might need to inspect accesses ;)

Comment: Norton sure doesn't record every access through ports 135 - 139.  I'm pretty sure, most firewalls **don't** audit those ports, due to performance concerns.