# Is network access logged any where on windows by default

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares

[I accidentally shared my C drive – what should I be worried about?](https://superuser.com/questions/334552/i-accidentally-shared-my-c-drive-what-should-i-be-worried-about)
and would like to know who may have accessed my files. Is this information stored any where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default on Windows 7 there is no logging of network activity.  It may be enabled, you can check.  If it isn't enabled, then can enable it.

To enable auditing do the following:

- Open Control panel
- Administrative Tools
- Local Security Policy
- Open Local Policies
- Audit Policy

From there you can enable auditing events.

If auditing is enabled then you can view the events in the Security Event log.

To view events:

- Open Control panel
- Administrative Tools
- Event Viewer
- Security

Answer (score 0):

You have little to nothing to worry about.  Even if you gave people read/write permission thought the share, the file systems security takes a higher precedence and no one without appropriate permissions would be able to do anything.

In other words, they could not do anything they could not have already done before the share.

Comment: Of course if the guest account was enabled, he had users with no passwords, or had granted more permissions then required then he may have cause for concern.  Your answer doesn't seem to directly answer the question.

Comment: @Zoredache Your points are irrelevant.  The question is about a network share, nothing you mentioned would have access to the file system through a share.